# Php registration page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a sign up page for my website in php . In my code I put if the username , password confirm password and/or email is empty it would give then an error , which it does , but it still says that the user was created . I don't want that to happen . If any of the user fields are empty I want them to go back to the sign up page and fill out the missing fields . All it does is give the echo statement and then it says user was created .

sign up.php:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 <title>Sign Up</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

 <h2 style="text-align: right"><b style="font-size: 25px">Sign Up Below</b></h2>
   <form name="registration" method="post" action="process2.php">
   <p align="right"><input type="text" name="username" size="35" id="Username" placeholder="User Name" /></p> 
   <br></br>
   <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password" size="35"  id="p w" placeholder="Password" /></p>
   <br></br>
  <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password2" size="35"  id="pw2" placeholder="Confirm Password" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <p align="right"><input type="text" name="email" size="35"  id="Email" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
    <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
   </form>

    <h3 style="font-size: 20px"><a href="register.php">Go Back To Home Screen</a>    </h3>  
   </body>
     </html>
   <?php

 if(empty($username)){ echo"Please enter a username to sign up.<br />";}  else {} 
 if(empty($pw)){echo"Please enter a password to sign up.<br />";}  else {}
 if(empty($pw2)){echo"Please confirm your password to sign up.<br />";}   else {}
 if(empty($email)){ echo"Please enter a email to sign up.<br />";}  else {}

?>
```

Process2.php:

```
<?php
   include("db.php");

                    if(empty($username)){ echo"Please enter a username to sign up.<br />";}  else {} 
                    if(empty($pw)){echo"Please enter a password to sign up.   <br />";}  else {}
                    if(empty($pw2)){echo"Please confirm your password to sign up.<br />";}  else {}
                    if(empty($email)){ echo"Please enter a email to sign up.<br />";}  else {}

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {
                 $username = $_POST['username'];
                 $pw = $_POST['password'];
                 $pw2 = $_POST['password2'];
                 $email = $_POST['email'];

       // validate and sanitize all of these inputs
       // and see that they are not blank at the same time

       // Do your MySql here to find the $username and 
       // bring out result of find in $username_result

                    if($username_result > 0){
                    echo "This username is in use.<a href= signup.php>Enter a different username</a> ";
                    // exit; // or send them back to registration page
                    } else {
                    // it is not in use so put it in
                    $pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
                    $pw2 = password_hash($pw2, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 8));

                    $sql = "INSERT into users VALUES(null, '$username', '$pw', '$pw2', '$email')";

                       if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){                                  
                       // if insert checked as successful echo username and password saved successfully
                       echo"Your user was created. <a href= signin.php>Click here to login </a><br />";
                       }else{
                       echo "Sorry there has been an error, please try  again.";   // and send them back to registration page 
                       }   
                    }
            }else{
            echo "The passwords do not match. <a href= signup.php>Try again</a><br />";  // and send them back to registration page
            }    
}
?>
```

So basically what I tried is putting the if the fields are empty statements before the code that sends the information to the database it doesn't work . I tried putting it after the code that sends the information to database it didn't work . I also tried putting it on the sign up page but it didn't work either .

What I want to happen is if any of the fields are empty nothing will be sent to the database . Can someone help me ?

update :

```
  <?php
  if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) ||  empty($_POST['password2']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['submit']))     {
       $error = "";
       if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        $error .= "Please enter a username. ";
        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        $error .= "Please enter a password. ";
        if(empty($_POST['password2']))
        $error .= "Please confirm your password. ";
       if(empty($_POST['email']))
        $error .= "Please enter your email. ";
     }

     include("db.php");
     ?>

     <html>
     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

   <h2 style="text-align: right"><b style="font-size: 25px">Sign Up Below</b></h2>
    <form name="registration" method="post">
    <p align="right"><input type="text" name="username" size="35" id="Username" placeholder="User Name" /></p> 
     <br></br>
     <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password" size="35"  id="p w" placeholder="Password" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password2" size="35"  id="pw2" placeholder="Confirm Password" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <p align="right"><input type="text" name="email" size="35"  id="Email" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
     <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
     </form>
      <?php
      if ($error)
    echo $error;
   ?> 
  <h3 style="font-size: 20px"><a href="register.php">Go Back To Home Screen</a>    </h3>  
    </body>
     </html>
    <?php
     }
     else if (($_POST['submit'])){                      
             if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {
                 $username = $_POST['username'];
                 $pw = $_POST['password'];
                 $pw2 = $_POST['password2'];
                 $email = $_POST['email'];

       // validate and sanitize all of these inputs
       // and see that they are not blank at the same time

       // Do your MySql here to find the $username and 
       // bring out result of find in $username_result

                    if($username_result > 0){
                    echo "This username is in use.<a href= signup.php>Enter a different username</a> ";
                    // exit; // or send them back to registration page
                    } else {
                    // it is not in use so put it in
                    $pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
                    $pw2 = password_hash($pw2, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 8));

                    $sql = "INSERT into users VALUES(null, '$username', '$pw', '$pw2', '$email')";

                       if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){                                  
                       // if insert checked as successful echo username and password saved successfully
                       echo"Your user was created. <a href= signin.php>Click here to login </a><br />";
                       }else{
                       echo "Sorry there has been an error, please try again.";   // and send them back to registration page 
                       }   
                    }
            }else{
            echo "The passwords do not match. <a href= signup.php>Try  again</a><br />";  // and send them back to registration page
            }    
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: you need to make the process stop when something is left empty. Your logic is off, so `if{...} else{...}`. and all of `if(empty($username))` etc. there's nothing assigned before it. all of those belong inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` and this is in the wrong spot `if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {`

Comment: then this doesn't hold water `if($username_result > 0){` where's the SELECT query for that?

Comment: all of my code is inside of that

Comment: @Fred-ii- where am i suppose to put if the passwords equal each other ? And all of my code is inside of if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}

Comment: you have been given an answer below

Comment: this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35054040/4198099

Comment: check first you have received all $_POST values properly or not. If not then redirect back using header('Location: your_page.php'); exit; OR show errors as displayed in above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place some of the signup and process code in the same page like this in signup.php (notice I have also removed the "action" code from the form tag:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password2']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['submit'])){
    $error = "";
    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
            $error .= "Please enter a username. ";
        if(empty($_POST['password']))
            $error .= "Please enter a password. ";
        if(empty($_POST['password2']))
            $error .= "Please confirm your password. ";
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
            $error .= "Please enter your email. ";
    }

?>

<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 <title>Sign Up</title>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

 <h2 style="text-align: right"><b style="font-size: 25px">Sign Up Below</b></h2>
   <form name="registration" method="post">
   <p align="right"><input type="text" name="username" size="35" id="Username" placeholder="User Name" /></p> 
   <br></br>
   <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password" size="35"  id="p w" placeholder="Password" /></p>
   <br></br>
  <p align="right"><input type="password" name="password2" size="35"  id="pw2" placeholder="Confirm Password" /></p>
    <br></br>
    <p align="right"><input type="text" name="email" size="35"  id="Email" placeholder="E-mail" /></p>
    <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
   </form>
<?php
    if ($error)
       echo $error;
?> 
    <h3 style="font-size: 20px"><a href="register.php">Go Back To Home Screen</a>    </h3>  
   </body>
     </html>
<?php
}
else if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
    //place most of the code from your process.php code here
    echo "processing";
}
```

Comment: I forgot a couple of closing brackets in my code. It is fixed now.

Comment: It works now . But how do I send it to the process file when the user clicks sumit ?

Comment: You don't need a process file. You can place whatever processing code you want into the section at the bottom that I commented for you.

Comment: If i put my process code in the bottom it says user has been created and I didn't put in any fields required . So how can I send it to the process file if the fields are all filled in ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean. You do not need a processing file. The file above is divided into two sections, a section to display the form and a section to do the processing. Place all your processing code right where I put the comment in your else if section. (Note: You can change the else if... to just an else but I left the condition there so it is easier for you to understand that this is where the form is doing its processing.)

Comment: Also, on the if statement located on the 2nd line of the above file, you can also add a check to the end of the line like this: ` || $_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']` and then create an error that says "Passwords do not match" the same way I created the other errors. That way you don't need to include this in your processing section.

Comment: I just put the code you told me to put in my post but now it's telling me  :( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: username_result in C:\wamp\www\interpage\signup.php on line 59

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\wamp\www\interpage\signup.php on line 69

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\interpage\signup.php on line 69

Comment: and it's giving me the else echo : Sorry there has been an error, please try again.

Comment: When I enter the info and click submit it says that the user has been created but when I look in the database the username , pw , pw2, and email fields all say 0

Comment: Yes, you still have many errors inside your program. Do you understand general programming concepts? If not, I recommend you go through some good PHP tutorials. There are some good ones on YouTube as well as https://www.codecademy.com/. Once you learn the basics you should research what common error messages mean. All of the errors above are quite basic. For example, your first error "Undefined variable: username_result ... on line 59" indicates that on line 59 you are trying to check use the variable $username_result but you have never stored anything in it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to signup.php when validation fails..For this you can check the input and if either of it empty then you can redirect in process2.php as:

```
if(empty($username) || empty($pw) || empty($pw2) || empty($email))
{
    header( "refresh:5;url=signup.php" ); 
} else {
     //You can do your things here..    
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\interpage\process2.php on line 5

Comment: It's because @pritesh forgot to close the opening parenthesis on the first line above.

Answer (score 0):

firstly check your connection to the database also check your users table if the field is **nullable** if it so then you might wanna put some try-catch block on your code to see the errors.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a little bit on your suggestions.